# Getting form input into ajax

Tags: javascript, php

I have a functioning PHP page with AJAX call. What Im trying to do now is to get a user input via a text input and then send thet through _GET into ajax. My code looks like this:

```
<body onload="test()">
<script>
function test () {
var options = {
chart : {
    renderTo : 'container',
    type : 'spline',
    zoomType: 'x',
},
series: [{
        name: '',
        data: []
}]
};
year = document.form1.year.value;

$.ajax({
    url : "data.php?year="+year,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (json) {
        options.series[0].name = json['name'];
        options.series[0].data = json['data'];
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    },
});
}
 </script>
<form name="form1">
<input type="text" name="year" value="2012">
</form>
</body>
```

Unfortunately for some reason it does not work, although when I alert "year" the value is correct and corresponds to what is inside the text input.

Comment: Have you checked with the browser developer tools to see whether the outgoing URL is OK, and what the response is? Can you tell from server-side logging whether the year is correctly making into your PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, never mind, Im an idiot I solved it already... I accidentaly left the value fixed to 2012 - I did that when I was testing it and forgot to delete it.